# protocol for transfering binary data in local network

Tags: sockets, windows-7, directshow, rpc, data-transfer

I have two computers connected by ethernet in a local network. The computers run Windows 7.

A video input device (monitoring a physics experiment) is connected to Computer A. I use DirectShow to process this input. The processed images (with added annotations, adjusted color palettes, deinterlacing,...) should be transfered to a second Computer B, that runs a harddisk recorder (by [Geutebrück](http://www.geutebrueck.com/)). On Computer B I have access to the harddisk recorder API to hand over the data from Computer A.

So far I have read about RPC as a possible way of transfering data. I would probably have to write a DirectShow sink filter, that implements an RPC client for computer A and some code for computer B, implementing an RPC server. However reading into this topic I came across MOTM, Corba and a lot more acronyms, indicating that the problem is not trivial.

I'd like to know if the approach above is reasonable or if there are any major pitfalls. Maybe there is an important constraint, that I have overlooked? And if there is a more reasonable approach, what would it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to need DirectShow on Computer B just for storage purposes. Get your data out of DirectShow pipeline (via sink filter, custom renderer, Sample Grabber whatsoever) and transfer to Computer B over regular networking (sockets, pipes etc).

Since it does not have to be compliant to anything, you can design a simple protocol and send data over TCP connection between the hosts. Media sample properties and payload going over the connection.